# How do I make a derived class from this one that requires a template argument list?

Tags: c++

Edit: corrected code

I’m trying to make a class derived from a template base class. When compiling the error received is “Use of class template requires template argument list”.
Here's the declared class that causes the error:

```
template <class TBase>
class Class1 : public BaseClassName
{
};
```

This is what the base class resembles.

```
template <class TBase> class BaseClassName;

template <class T> void Callback1(int value1, BaseClassName <T> session);
template <class T> void Callback2(int value1, BaseClassName <T> session);
friend void Method1(int value1);

template <class TBase>
class BaseClassName : public TBase
{
    template <class T> friend void Callback1(int value1, BaseClassName <T> session);
    template <class T> friend void Callback2(int value1, BaseClassName <T> session);
    friend void Method1(int value1);
    // Other methods…
};
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: `template <class TBase> class Class1 : public BaseClassName<TBase>`?

Comment: I tried that and I get a syntax error, missing ',' before '<'.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of `BaseClassName` in your second code snippet.

Comment: Thanks. semi-colon added.

Comment: Ahhh fud. This is why I like [mre]s. My fingers auto-fixed than missing semi when I hacked out a compliable example to make sure I wasn't on crack. Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/oM136b6rq Mind you, I could be fixing the wrong thing.

Comment: Is there still an issue?

Comment: Yes this is still an issue. As posted now the template argument error still occurs.

Comment: I take the code unaltered and pop it into a compiler, I get a whole bunch of errors, but not the one you're talking about. A [mre] is a must if you want this question to come to a reasonable conclusion.